# Maven Snapshot Deployment policy Doubts

Tags: maven

as of now we used to check out entire project, and compile all the projects at all the time.

so now we want to checkout only which we want to modify,,so for that we implemented version to easily track where the modifications happens.

```
Let say we have project A
    Project B
    Project C
```

if i want to modify project C and i want to checkout only project C but project C has dependencies on A and B.

A and B has to download from the nexus.
for every modifications on A and B, deploy the artifacts into nexus, and C will get those changes from nexus.

as i am mew to this concept, can any one let me know how to make this workable properly..
**Questions**

as i observed all snapshots are on time stamp based,which dependencies will download newest or oldest,
if i want older snapshot as a dependency,what i have to do?
any best practice suggestions?

**Adding Error Code:-**

when using -T 1.5C i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenExecutionRequestsBuilderException: Must provide a thread count for -T
at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:192)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven32Launcher.java:153)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:130)
... 22 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must provide a thread count for -T
at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.populateRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:982)
at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:172)
... 24 more
  ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
  java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to Maven [/opt/ibm/java-x86_64-60/bin/java, -cp, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-agent-1.6.jar:/opt/apache/apache-maven-3.2.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/opt/apache/apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main, /opt/apache/apache-maven-3.2.5, /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.49.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-interceptor-1.6.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.6.jar, 45090] failed
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:756)
at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:849)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenExecutionRequestsBuilderException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:624)
at hudson.remoting.MultiClassLoaderSerializer$Input.resolveClass(MultiClassLoaderSerializer.java:116)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1611)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1516)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1349)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:185)
at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:218)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Are you aware of `mvn -pl project clean package`?

Comment: yes...for our big project we have 6 projects and each project 60 to 80 modules...and each has dependencies on others...and checkout all the code is taking some time...so that is the reason to reduce the checkout time we went to the above mentioned way...is it good practice?

Comment: What is your build time (5-10 Mins?) ? How many llines of code (measured by SonarQube) ? How many tests are being executed? Which Maven Version do you use? Are you using up-to-date- maven plugins?  Do you use `mvn -T3 ...` ? Are we talking about a cintinuous integration solution like Jenkins?

Comment: cureent build time 50 min....no tests and using 2.2 maven...i am ware of Parallel builds but maven 2 wont support...is there any altenate way.... we have to concerns to reduce time in jenkins and to reduce the checkout time for developer

Comment: First move to Maven 3 cause  [Maven 2 is EoL](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-announce/201503.mbox/%3C20150320213920.6AE4B17423%40minotaur.apache.org%3E). How many lines of code? How many tests do you have? How long is the checkout time? What kind of VCS do you use? I'm working on a build with 280 modules incl. ca. 4000 tests takes less than 10 minutes. And using `-T` can speed up things dramatically. (reduces by 50% are possible)...You can check if you can parallelize the build by using jenkins (each module a job in jenkins) with upstream/downstream relations.

Comment: Test's are there but not sure about the count and checkout time 10 mins(in jenkins)   and some developers are working from remote by connecting remotely for them 40 mins and using svn ...  as mentioned by you You can check if you can parallelize the build by using jenkins (each module a job in jenkins) with upstream/downstream relations  means in your environemnt 280 jobs are there?

Comment: If you have running jenkins than there you can see the number of tests which you should record of cause (Maven build job type). Taking 10 minutes to checkout how many files in SVN sounds very slow? Furthermore a full checkout for developers in not needed an svn upd is enough. On Jenkins this is a different story. Apart from that i have not the need to parallelize the build by Jenkins. I can use `-T...`of maven.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise..i tried with & parallel build's by using -T 1.5C, it reduced only 15 mins....is there any alternative's to reduce more time..And jenkins clean install is taking more time when compared to command line execution...any suggestions?

Comment: How many cores do you have on Jenkins and on the command line you have tested? Sometimes you should check if `mvn -T4 ...` does more instead of `-T 1.5C`...I would start with `mvn -T2 clean deploy` and go further with `mvn -T3 clean deploy` and `mvn -T4 clean deploy`...and so on...and see where the minimum is...Have you checked the times in Jenkins how long steps take (timestamper plugin is very helpfull)...How long does the upload to the repository manager take? Have you checked the size which is transfered to the repository manager ?

Comment: In some blog's i read parallel builds are not suitable for all the builds, but in my case build is success...to know 100% ut's working is there any tips...have you gaced any problems in your environment with this parallel builds

Comment: The blog's are simply wrong sorry to say that (I'm reading this over and over). I'm doing this in the meantime for more than a year and did before as well. You should take care if your plugins are uptodate ...Have you checked the points i mentioned?

Comment: yes  khmarbaise...in my case 1.5 c looks better...and in your projects all modules are same versions or different versions? if we go different versions is there any overhead?

Comment: We have a single mutli module build which contains 280 modules...all versions for the modules are the same, cause it will be released all in once...Why would you like to go with different versions?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, i am getting one error when using -T 1.5C, i added the error code in the quetion..have you seen this type of error in past?

Comment: The error message gives me the hint ` Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must provide a thread count for -T` that something during the configuration has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use older states of SNAPSHOTs this can be achieved by defining the appropriate version in your pom:

The [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) can help in such cases to [lock-snapshots](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/lock-snapshots-mojo.html) or to [unlock-snapshots](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/unlock-snapshots-mojo.html).

Apart from that you should be aware of the [update policy](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) which can change in the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file. Or you can manually force to update via:

```
mvn -U ...
```